# Pivot the first ten values of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider two tables, one containing the details of work (`cases`) to be carried out, and one describing what work has been performed on each cases (`activities`).

The `cases` table is roughly 20million rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #cases
    (CASEID int, DETAILS varchar(1))

INSERT INTO #cases
    (CASEID, DETAILS)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C')
;
```

The `activities` table is roughly 180million rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #activities
    (ACTIVITYID int, CASEID int, CODE varchar(3), STARTDATE date)

INSERT INTO #activities
    (ACTIVITYID, CASEID, CODE, STARTDATE)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '00', '2018-01-01'),
    (2, 1, '110', '2018-02-01'),
    (3, 1, '900', '2018-03-01'),
    (4, 1, '910', '2018-05-01'),
    (5, 1, '920', '2018-04-01'),
    (6, 2, '900', '2018-01-01'),
    (7, 2, '110', '2018-02-01'),
    (8, 2, '900', '2018-03-01'),
    (9, 3, '00', '2018-01-01'),
    (10, 3, '123', '2018-02-01')
;
```

It is not ideal - but I need to find a way to create a wide table containing case details, and then details of the first 10 activities with a code in the range 900-999.

Some cases will have more than 10 activities in that range - some cases will have none.

The output I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```
CASEID  DETAILS CODE1st900  STARTDATE1st900 CODE2nd900  STARTDATE2nd900 CODE3rd900  STARTDATE3rd900
1   A   900 01/01/2018 00:00:00 920 01/04/2018 00:00:00 910 01/05/2018 00:00:00
2   B   900 01/01/2018 00:00:00 900 01/03/2018 00:00:00     
3   C
```

Ultimately I am not sure whether some kind of clever pivot is the best approach here, joining each set of values with a subquery, or a cursor which is typically how my organisation has created this sort of data previously.

DBFiddle to play with here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5eef2de402726218a8472880ef0bab85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the volume of data, I would do this using `apply`:

```
select c.*, a.*
from cases c outer apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then code end) as code_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then startdate end) as startdate_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then code end) as code_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then startdate end) as startdate_2,
             . . .
      from (select top (10) a.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by a.caseid order by a.startdate) as seqnum
            from activities a
            where a.caseid = c.caseid and
                  a.code between 900 and 999
           ) a
      ) a;
```

This should have much better performance than solutions using `pivot` or `group by`, because the data from `cases` does not need to be aggregated.  The aggregations are taking place ten rows at a time as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually we'd prefer `PIVOT` but there's no syntax currently for pivoting multiple columns simultaneously. So we'll use conditional aggregation instead:

```
declare @cases table (CASEID int, DETAILS varchar(1))
INSERT INTO @cases (CASEID, DETAILS) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C');

declare @activities table (ACTIVITYID int, CASEID int, CODE varchar(3), STARTDATE date)
INSERT INTO @activities (ACTIVITYID, CASEID, CODE, STARTDATE) VALUES
(1, 1, '00', '2018-01-01'),
(2, 1, '110', '2018-02-01'),
(3, 1, '900', '2018-03-01'),
(4, 1, '910', '2018-05-01'),
(5, 1, '920', '2018-04-01'),
(6, 2, '900', '2018-01-01'),
(7, 2, '110', '2018-02-01'),
(8, 2, '900', '2018-03-01'),
(9, 3, '00', '2018-01-01'),
(10, 3, '123', '2018-02-01');

select
    c.CASEID,
    c.DETAILS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN CODE END) as Code1st,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN STARTDATE END) as Start1st,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN CODE END) as Code2nd,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN STARTDATE END) as Start2nd
from
    @cases c
        left join
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASEID ORDER BY STARTDATE) rn
     from @activities
     where CODE BETWEEN 900 and 999) a
        on
            c.CASEID = a.CASEID and
            a.rn <= 10
group by c.CASEID,c.DETAILS
```

I've shown pivoting the first pair of pairs above. Hopefully you can see how it extends for the remaining 8.